# Cannot resubmit a form after it has been reset using jquery without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit, reset

I have a "Share Link" form that submits using ajax. After the form is submitted it is hidden and a popup confirmation box is displayed with a link to "Share Again". If I click on "Share Again" the form fields are reset and the form is displayed again. However it never gets submitted the second time.

I don't think it's the Captcha causing the problem because the captcha is just there for show. The form will submit regardless of correctly entered captcha challenge or not. There's a honeypot field to handle spam filtering.

Here is the jquery I am using

```
$("#sharethis").submit(function() {
    $('.loading').show(); // display loading animation
    $('#sharethis').fadeOut('slow'); // hide the form after submission
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    //Do the AJAX post
    $.post($("#sharethis").attr("action"), $("#sharethis").serialize(), function(data){
        //do stuff here...
          $('.loading').fadeOut('slow'); //hide the loading animation after successful post
          $('#share-confirmation').fadeIn('slow'); // show the popup with link to share again
    });
    //Important. Stop the normal POST

    return false;
});
$('#share-confirmation .back-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of share again link
  $('#share-confirmation').fadeOut('slow'); // hide popup
  $('#sharethis').fadeIn('slow'); // show form
  $('#sharethis')[0].reset(); //reset form fields
});
```

And the form itself:

```
<div id="share-form" class="form-wrapper">
<div class="close-button share-toggle"></div>
<div class="loading"></div> 
<div id="share-confirmation" class="done">
<div class="form-text">Email Sent!</div>
<a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>" class="back-link form-text">Share again</a>
<a href="?q=advanced-property-search" class="share-link form-text">Go Back to Offerings</a>
</div>
<div id="share-error"><span class="form-text">Email could not be sent</span></div>
<form id="sharethis" name="sharethis" action="sites/all/themes/greysteel/mailer/share-listing.php" method="post">
<label for="shareto">To Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="shareto" class="form-text" size="30" maxlength="128" required/>
<label for="sharefrom">From Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="sharefrom" id="sharefrom" class="form-text" size="30" maxlength="128" required/>
<label for="sharefromemail">From Email</label>
<input type="email" name="sharefromemail" class="form-text" size="30" maxlength="128" required/>
<div id="sendcopy" class="form-text">Send me a copy</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="sharecc" id="sharecc" value="1" />
<label for="sharemsg">Message:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="sharelisttitle" value="<?php print $title; ?>" />
<textarea name="sharemsg" class="form-textarea"></textarea>
<label for="shareurl">URL:</label>
<div class="form-text">http://greysteel.com<?php print $node_url; ?></div>
<input type="hidden" name="shareurl" value="http://greysteel.com<?php print $node_url; ?>" />
<?php if(isset($content['field_email_property_logo'])): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sharelogo" value="<?php print file_create_url($node->field_email_property_logo['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" />
<?php else: ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sharelogo" value="<?php print file_create_url($node->field_property_image['und'][0]['uri']); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(isset($content['field_property_memorandum'])): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="ca-agreement" value="<?php print render($content['field_property_memorandum']['#items']['0']['value']); ?>" />
 <?php endif; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="test" class="test-field" />
<div id="recaptcha1" class="captcha">

<img id="captcha" src="sites/all/themes/greysteel/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
  <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" /><br>
  <a href="#" class="form-text" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'sites/all/themes/greysteel/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>
</div> 
<input type="submit" id="share-submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="form-submit" /> 
</form>
<!--[if IE]><iframe class="cover" src="about:blank"></iframe><![endif]-->
</div>
```

Comment: The form is submitting when I try it. See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Vt52K/

Comment: The form submits the first time you try it. But after the first submission and you click on "Share Again" it doesn't submit (even though it says email sent, you never receive the email)

Comment: The form should send an email when it is submitted, which can't be tested on jsfiddle since there's no php mail function attached. I am going to add the php mailer script here since that could also be the source of the problem.

Comment: OK I figured out the problem. It was in fact the captcha .... The form  is being reset as expected but the captcha challenge session isn't being reset. FML

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace this

```
$("#sharethis").submit(function() {
```

by this

```
$(document).on('submit', '#sharethis', function(){
```

in your jQuery ?

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference unless he recreates the form dynamically after the first submission. He's just hiding it, not removing it.

Comment: Correct, after first successful submission the form is simply hidden. When you click on "Share Again" from the popup it resets the form and displays it again.